# Sharepoint list validation on branching

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, validation

I am reaching the limit of 1024 characters on list level validation due to branching.  I can't use field validation as I can't determine if a field is visible and decide whether to enforce the validation.

I've been using the excel style validation that is available from SharePoint.  I'm open to changing to another form of validation if available but I didn't realise this was a possibility before reading other posts on StackExchange.  Still unsure how to go about other methods.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.  I am fairly new to Share Point Lists and may have missed some obvious API for determining field visibility in field level validation.

I made a genuine attempt to search for the answer in stack exchange but came up short, apologies if I just didn't understand what to search for.

I am using sharepoint in Microsoft 365.

Comment: Apologize in advance if I misunderstand. I'm not sure what is "excel style validation". In Microsoft 365 world, you can integrate SharePoint with Power Apps and connect a canvas app from SharePoint Online to validate the columns. See this: https://techwizard.cloud/2020/02/08/powerapps-sharepoint-online-list-field-validation/.

Comment: By excel style validation I meant that it uses the same syntax as in excel.  Hopefully I don't have to go down the route of creating a Power App as I am just doing a favour for another area at work, but thanks for suggesting this :).

Comment: Hi Stephen. It does sound like you might benefit from creating a Power App form for your list. It does not take too much time. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form